# Django forms + errors in JSON + jquery syntax error

Tags: jquery, django, forms

I'm using a simple Django form with JSON validation. Following Jacobian method on how to expose form errors into a JSON object, I used this function:

```
def errors_to_json(errors):
# Force error strings to be un-lazied.
return simplejson.dumps(dict((k, map(unicode, v)) for (k,v) in errors.iteritems()))
```

However, when a form fails to validate, I encounter this jQuery syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
c.extend.globalEvaljquery.min.js:29
c.extend.httpDatajquery.min.js:132
c.extend.ajax.g.x.onreadystatechange
```

I think this SyntaxError is due to a bad JSON response, but I cannot find errors in this JSON:

```
{"title": ["This field is required."]}
```

I've tried with jQuery 1.5.1, 1.4.4, 1.4.2, using the

```
$.post()
```

method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I post the solution:

switched from

```
$.post()
```

to

```
$.ajax(url, function() {}, dataType:'JSON');
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
 function(data){
   console.log(data.name); // John
   console.log(data.time); //  2pm
 }, "json");
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/